# echo the created directory name

Tags: shell, scripting

I'm trying to echo the new directory that I'm creating in the script.

```
BACKUP_DIR=`mkdir /tmp/"$TICKET_NUM"_EAR_BACKUP_"$(date "+%Y%m%d")"`
echo $BACKUP_DIR
```

But, the newly created directory is echoed in the screen. Anything Im missing here?

Comment: look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668640/how-to-execute-command-stored-in-a-variable

Answer (score 1):

1. `mkdir -v` seems to print out the created directory, whereas `mkdir` is completely silent on my systems (tested on Mac OS X and Ubuntu Linux). However, you still need to parse out the directory name from this output:

```
    mkdir /tmp/foo
    (no output)

    mkdir -v /tmp/foo
    mkdir: created directory `/tmp/foo'

    DIR=$(mkdir -v /tmp/foo | cut -d\  -f4- | tr -d "'\`")
    echo $DIR
    /tmp/foo
```

So in your case:

```
BACKUP_DIR=$( mkdir /tmp/"$TICKET_NUM"_EAR_BACKUP_"$(date "+%Y%m%d")" | cut -d\  -f4- | tr -d "'\`" )
```

2. You might want to use the -p switch in order to create the full directory hierarchy. (Yes, `/tmp` will exist on MOST machines, but sometimes things can really be screwed up...).

Answer (score 0):

*var=`cmd`* catches output of cmd and stores in $var. But *mkdir* outputs nothing on success, so $BACKUP_DIR is empty.

> BACKUP_DIR="/tmp/"$TICKET_NUM"_EAR_BACKUP_"$(date "+%Y%m%d")
>
> mkdir $BACKUP_DIR
>
> echo $BACKUP_DIR

This should work.