# Running a command that is stored in a variable (including pipes and redirects)

Tags: bash, shell, espeak

I'm writing a script that functions as a "talking terminal" (you type in commands and it says the output) and so far my code is:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1=1 ]; do
echo -n "~>"
read COMMAND
espeak "$($COMMAND)"
done
```

and it works for simple commands:

```
bash$ ./talkingterminal.sh
~> ls
# espeak says "talkingterminal.sh"
```

but when I use pipes etc:

```
bash$ ./talkingterminal.sh
~>ip addr | grep inet
Command "|" is unknown, try "ip addr help".
~>
```

and that command works in bash and gives the expected output.
any help?
thanks,
Martin

Comment: Not an answer, but for an explanation, I'd say it's because command separation happens in the initial word splitting phase, so expanding the command can't make one command into a pipeline of two anymore. Ref: [How to execute command stored in a variable?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4668800/12274) Hence `eval`.

Answer (score 2):

This is a rare case where `eval` is appropriate; you just putting a thin wrapper around what is already unlimited access to the command line. More importantly, you aren't modifying `COMMAND` in any unexpected ways. What the user types is what will be executed.

```
#!/bin/bash
while : ; do
    IFS= read -rp "~> " COMMAND
    espeak "$(eval "$COMMAND")"
done
```

A few notes:

1. The `read` builtin in `bash` can display a custom prompt using the `-p` option.
2. Use the `:` or `true` commands, which always succeed, to set up an infinite loop.
3. Use the `-r` option and an empty value for `IFS` to ensure that `COMMAND` is set to the *exact* line typed by the user.
4. Quote `$COMMAND` so that the entire string is passed to `eval` without any previous shell parsing.
5. Note that this still cannot handle multi-line input in the same fashion as the shell itself. (For example, a line like `for x in 1 2 3; do` will not prompt you for the body of the loop.)

Comment: Downvoters: this is what `eval` is actually *intended* for. The OP already wants to execute arbitrary code, rather than assuming `eval` will only execute the intended subset of code it can execute.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to use `eval`:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1=1 ]; do
echo -n "~>"
read COMMAND
espeak "$(eval $COMMAND)"
done
```

Then you can print output to the shell as well easily:

```
#!/bin/bash
while [ 1=1 ]; do
echo -n "~>"
read COMMAND
OUTPUT="$(eval $COMMAND)"
echo $OUTPUT
espeak "$($OUTPUT)"
done
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to use the "-r" option? This option avoids interpreting special characters. Additionally you have to remove the external $() in the line:

```
espeak "$($COMMAND)"
```

It should be:

```
espeak "$(COMMAND)"
```

Comment: `read` is not the problem; the problem is that expanding `$COMMAND` like this passes `|` as an argument to `ipaddr` rather than parsing the entire string as a pipeline.

Comment: `$(COMMAND)` would attempt to run the literal command "COMMAND", not the value of the `COMMAND` parameter.