# How does quote in a cmd string work and how does the quote interact with eval for bash script?

Tags: bash, grep, eval, quote

I tried the commands in a bash script.

```
#!/bin/bash
cmd='pgrep -d " " -f "python test.py"'
$cmd 

cmd2=(pgrep -d \" \" -f \"python test.py\")
${cmd2[@]}
```

Both don't work returning `pgrep: only one pattern can be provided` as you expect. however both work with `eval` command like the below.

```
eval $cmd
eval ${cmd2[@]}
```

The errors seem from using quote(`"`) but I don't have any idea why and how `eval` command interacts with the quote in here though I have tried to understand with the below description.

```
DESCRIPTION
       The eval utility shall construct a command by concatenating arguments together, separating
       each with a <space>. The constructed command shall be read and executed by the shell.


EXAMPLES
          foo=10 x=foo
          y='$'$x
          echo $y
          $fooeval y='$'$x
          echo $y
          10
```

Could you give me the explanation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to execute command stored in a variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668640/how-to-execute-command-stored-in-a-variable)

Comment: Don't store commands in variables.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the output here and see if it helps.

```
showArgs(){
  test $# = 0 && return
  echo "arg:" "$1"
 shift
 showArgs "$@"
}
cmd='pgrep -d " " -f "python test.py"'
echo Without eval ---------
showArgs $cmd
echo With eval --------
eval showArgs $cmd
```

Also try `set -x` to enable debug output.