# Bash: Command stored in variable not executing

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have the following script file `temp.sh`

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
this_command="exec \"/bin/ls\""
$this_command
```

It throws this error

```
./temp.sh: line 3: /home/user/"/bin/ls": No such file or directory
```

But if I run

```
#! /usr/bin/env bash
exec "/bin/ls"
```

It runs fine.
Could I know what the problem is and how I can get that command stored in a variable to run?
Thanks

Comment: Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668640/how-to-execute-command-stored-in-a-variable), you could do `eval $cmd` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Double quotes are special to the shell. If you enter

```
exec "/bin/ls"
```

"quote removal" kicks in, and what the shell really sees is two words, `exec` and `/bin/ls`.

If you run the same command from a variable, it's different: see "Expansion" in `man bash`:

> Quote Removal
>          After  the  preceding  expansions,  all unquoted occurrences of the characters \, ', and "
>          that did not result from one of the above expansions are removed.

As the quotes came from variable expansion, they aren't removed.

Just store the command without quotes:

```
this_command='exec /bin/ls'
$this_command
```

For more complex commands involving special characters or filenames containing whitespace, using an array variable might seem better

```
command=(ls -d 'dir name containing spaces')
"{command[@]}"
```

Note that wildcards will still be evaluated during the command construction, not when the command runs.

```
$ touch 'a b'
$ command=(ls *\ *)
$ cd ..
$ "${command[@]}"
ls: cannot access 'a b': No such file or directory
```

Comment: I only get the entire command string during runtime. And I get it exactly like how a user would enter it in an interactive shell. Getting rid of those double quotes is problematic in itself

Comment: Good luck reimplementing the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is use of those nested quotes while storing command in a variable.

For this simple example you can get away by using:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
this_command="exec /bin/ls"
$this_command
```

Though that won't work with more complex commands lines. For that, you are better off using a shell array:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# store command line an array
cmd=(exec /bin/ls -l 'some file'*)

# execute command line
"${cmd[@]}"
```

This example will run following command in your shell:

```
ls -l 'some file'*
```

**Check** [BashFAQ/050: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: I only get the entire command string during runtime. And I get it exactly like how a user would enter it in an interactive shell.  Let me see if I can use your approach.. gimme a min

Comment: Yeah its one string that I'm working with...eval seems easier than converting into an array and then doing this.

Comment: Just keep in mind `eval` is a huge risk and someone can run any harmful command on your shell.

Comment: Yeah, but wouldn't this suggestion have the exact same effect, If I were to treat the entire command as a single string? Please correct me if I am wrong, I'm still learning :)

Comment: In the FAQ link I shared above, there is a section **5. I'm constructing a command based on information that is only known at run time**